# javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: In &lt;parseDate&gt;, a parse locale can not be established

Tags: jsp, jstl, atg, oracle-commerce

Does anyone can identify the root cause of this error? Using fmt:parseDate tag , to parse the date in correct format. I can't seem to find a way to replicate what causes this exception.
MY date format is like for example:"2015-08-06 13:13:30.59"
Pulling order.submittedDate value from DB and trying get dd from the date object.

```
<fmt:parseDate value="${order.submittedDate}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" var="formatedDate"/>
<fmt:formatDate pattern="dd" value="${formatedDate}" var="submittedDay"/>
```

find below the full stacktrace

```
    javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: In &lt;parseDate&gt;, a parse locale can not be established
at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.fmt.ParseDateSupport.doEndTag(ParseDateSupport.java:138)
at org.apache.jsp.tp_002dapp.emailTemplate.orderConfirmationEmail_jsp._jspx_meth_fmt_005fparseDate_005f0(orderConfirmationEmail_jsp.java:1323)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the code below which will pass en_GB as the locale - you will need to replace this with your locale:

```
 <fmt:parseDate value="${order.submittedDate}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" var="formatedDate" parseLocale="en_GB" />
```

If you want to soft code the locale you could do it as follows in ATG:

```
<dsp:importbean var="requestLocale" bean="/atg/dynamo/servlet/RequestLocale" />
<fmt:setLocale value="${requestLocale.locale}"/>
<fmt:parseDate value="${order.submittedDate}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" var="formatedDate" />
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Send the request with Accept-Language Header

Got this error when trying to make request with java client. Browsers by default send the Accept-Language Header. So the client request should contain this header.

```
Accept-Language: en-GB
```

Comment: In Oracle Commerce/ATG which this might not work as the locale might be based on the site you have chosen, rather than your browser header.